# P Langauage to NP Reduction in Polynomial Time

Tags: np-complete, np, decision-problem

Let L be a language in P. Prove it is polynomial time reducible to any language in NP, including any language in P, which contains at least one string but doesn’t contain all the strings.

I tried solving this, One solution I can think of is making a deterministic Turing machine that recognizes the problem P in polynomial time and then I can convert the Turing machine into a non-deterministic machine but that will that exponential time. Can we do a conversion in polynomial time?

Comment: Your first step is fine, but the second part is much than what you suggest. Note that you do not have to consider all instances of the language you are reducing to, only those that you need.

Comment: Hint for a proof: suppose that $L_{Target} \in NP$ and exists $y \in L_{Target}$ and $z \notin L_{Target}$. If $L$ is in $P$ then exists a polynomial time (decider) $M$ such that $M(x) = Yes$ if and only if $x \in L$. You can build $M'$ that acts in this way: on input $x$ it computes $M(x)$ and if $M(x) = yes$ then it writes $y$ on the tape, if $M(x) = no$ then it writes $z$ ...what does the function computed by $M'$ represent? (note that it is a function $f: L \to L_{Target}$) ... does $M'$ run in polynomial time ?